# Start OpenVPN client by a service - TLS error

Tags: service, vpn, systemd, openvpn

I want to start a OpenVPN client by a service. So I wrote this service (located in `/etc/systemd/system/`):

```
[Unit]
Description=...
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/client.conf
ExecPreStart=/usr/sbin/rngd /dev/urandom
ExecPreStart=/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My `client.conf` looks like this:

```
client
dev-tun
remote ...
proto udp
resolv-retry infinite
persist-tun
persist-key

# Cert files config...
# Cypher and auth config ...
```

Now I have the problem that I get an error when the Service started OpenVPN:

```
TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to oocur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
```

The interesting fact is that the error doesn't occure after I restart the service (also immediate after system start-up). The error occures only on the first launch of the service.
So I experimeted with `sleep` (up to 1 minute) in `ExecPreStart` or to create more entropy in `/dev/urandom` and to execute `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` (as you see in the service). Nothing helps.

What is the reason for that and how can I fix this? I don't want to write a script which only restarts the service once after startup.

**Edit/Update:**

I figured out that the error only occures if the OpenVPN client is startet "by" the system itself. I mean by a service or by crontab. Only if I start the service by myself (as `root` user) in a bash it works.

Comment: I’m not sure if it’s related to your problem, but the directive is called `ExecStartPre=`, not `ExecPreStart=`.

Answer (score 0):

Ordering your service after `network.target` is not enough to ensure internet connectivity. You need to order your service after `network-online.target` and also make it depend on it:

```
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
```

See [NetworkTarget on fd.o](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/) for more information.